# Get EC2 Bandwidth Usage By Instance ID

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

How do I get the instance bandwidth usage for NetworkIn and NetworkOut for an EC2 instance based on the instance ID using the PHP SDK.

So far what I have is...

```
<?php
require_once("../aws/Sdk.php");

use Aws\CloudWatch\CloudWatchClient;

$client = CloudWatchClient::factory(array(
    'profile' => 'default',
    'region'  => 'ap-southeast-2'
));

$dimensions = array(
    array('Name' => 'Prefix', 'Value' => ""),
);

$result = $client->getMetricStatistics(array(
    'Namespace'  => 'AWSSDKPHP',
    'MetricName' => 'NetworkIn',
    'Dimensions' => $dimensions,
    'StartTime'  => strtotime('-1 hour'),
    'EndTime'    => strtotime('now'),
    'Period'     => 3000,
    'Statistics' => array('Maximum', 'Minimum'),
));
```

I have a PHP cron job running every hour and I need to be able to get the bandwidth in and out for a specific EC2 instance to record in an internal database.

What I have above I have been able to piece together from the SDK documentation but from here I am kinda stumped.

I believe what I need is cloudwatch so would rather it be able to be done through this. I know that I can install a small program onto each server to report the bandwidth usage to a file on the server that I then SFTP into to download to our database but would rather it be done externally of any settings within the instance itself so that an instance admin can't cause issues with the bandwidth reporting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to get it working with...

```
<?php
require '../../aws.phar';
use Aws\CloudWatch\CloudWatchClient;

$cw = CloudWatchClient::factory(array(
    'key' => 'your-key-here',
    'secret' => 'your-secret-here',
    'region' => 'your-region-here',
    'version' => 'latest'
));

$metrics = $cw->listMetrics(array('Namespace' => 'AWS/EC2'));

//print_r($metrics);

$statsyo = $cw->getMetricStatistics(array(
    'Namespace'     => 'AWS/EC2',
    'MetricName'    => 'NetworkIn',
    'Dimensions'    => array(array('Name' => 'InstanceId', 'Value' => 'your-instance-id-here')),
    'StartTime'     => strtotime("2017-01-23 00:00:00"),
    'EndTime'       => strtotime("2017-01-23 23:59:59"),
    'Period'        => 86400,
    'Statistics'    => array('Average'),
    'Unit'          => 'Bytes'
));

echo($statsyo);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to calculate your bandwidth charge the same way AWS would, a better and more conclusive way would be to use VPC Flow Logs. You can subscribe your ENI to VPC flow logs (should be pretty cheap, they only charge for CloudWatch Logs costs, flow logs is free) then use the AWS SDK to pull from CloudWatch with GetLogEvents, and then sum up the bytes total.

Comment: Are you meaning that the CloudWatch NetworkIn and NetworkOut statistics are not accurate?

Comment: CloudWatch NetworkIn and NetworkOut will include some categories of data transfer that are not billed or metered for. It used to be described on this page but I cannot find it there now: https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/pricing/on-demand/ under "data transfer". Categories like windows licensing, DNS, etc. Shouldn't have a huge impact on data transfer numbers that you're pulling from CloudWatch